# how to add detailed dynamic topology on to a low poly model

Tags: mesh, uv, sculpting, remesh

i have created a robot model where all of his cables and wires had been sculpted by hand to give the wires an organic feel to them, though they look really neat at the moment and i still need to sculpts more onto them, i need to know how to turn this an put it on a low poly version of it, i have heard somewhere that you can create a backup model of the same mesh, which i did, and apparently you can transfer the detail onto the low poly model without giving it thousands of little polygons, i am making this character for a game, so i cant have my character cramped with polygons or it will crash the hell out of the game. if anyone could direct me to some information, or tell my upfront that would be really grateful

Comment: "you can transfer the detail onto the low poly model", you must be talking about baking the normals, you should look for tutorials about it

Comment: oh ok, when making normal, which i think it is just a texture on top of the model, will it still show the 3d aspect of different bumbs and seems on the model?

Comment: Yes, normal map gives your plain low poly models more depth and height, it works on some values that create normal map, (just to use simple example, for example it will say that white color is 1mm above your topology, and black color is 1mm under your topology and gradient between 2 colors is the rest of the height levels... you should check some information or tutorials about it

Comment: k i will check this out, thank you both for the amazing help